# in blender itself the mesh looks like this, though when I view it in a fbx viewer it looks like this, what could be the problem?

Tags: mesh, .fbx

[image]

what the title says basically, the left is what my model looks like in blender itself, but when I export it to FBX it looks like the picture on the right, why dont my windows look proper?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)